# Hot to auto-start an Azure Virtual Machine on public IP access?

Tags: azure, automation, power-saving, cost-management

On Azure, it seems possible to [Auto-stop your VM based on CPU utilization](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/auto-stop-your-vm-based-cpu-utilization-azure-automation-bassel-damra/)

For this to be effectively used for cost-saving, I need the VM to be auto-started on the next access to its public IP address.

This is a server which gets only a few hours of usage every week, and they are concentrated, so this could mean ~10X cost reduction...

Answer (score 2):

You could actually do something like that with something like Traffic Manager\Azure Function combination, but its probably better to move your workload to Azure Container Instances\Azure Functions, that would be a more native way of doing so.

If you wish to proceed with your design, you'd have to have some sort of load balancing between something that is always listening (like Azure Function) and a real VM. when you send a request to the endpoint Function will pick it up and start the vm, after that VM will pick up all the requests (it has to have a bigger weigth than the fucntion).

Comment: Thanks, I will try those "Functions"... Yet avoiding the extra cost of a Load Balancer. Or the Container instance cause it still requires a VM to run so it adds to cost + complexity. So I will see if I can shutdown the VM and take over the public IP from a `Function`, then do the reverse on any incoming request...

Comment: no, azure container instace doesnt require a vm to run. its abstracts that away from you. load balancer is free, so nothing to avoid.

Comment: Okay I am trying container since it takes very long to fully shutdown & start VMs. Still I don't see it available for the 12 months free trial, but let's see if I can automate it...

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am thinking of something similar